# @react-native-firebase/messaging error: cannot find symbol FirebaseInstanceId

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

Can't resolve this error in my React Native project, which uses **Firebase Cloud Messaging** module @react-native-firebase/messaging:

```
BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\messaging\ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
                              ^
  symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
  location: package com.google.firebase.iid
C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\messaging\ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
      .call(getExecutor(), () -> FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(authorizedEntity, scope))
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
  location: class ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule
C:\Users\...\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\messaging\android\src\main\java\io\invertase\firebase\messaging\ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule.java:135: error: cannot find symbol
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(authorizedEntity, scope);
        ^
  symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
  location: class ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule
3 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Tried:

- different **gradle** versions 6.9, 7.0, 7.0.1.
- different **google-services** versions 4.3.5, 4.3.6, 4.3.7
- applying **google-services** at the top and at the bottom of build.gradle app
- different **gradle plugin** versions 4.1.3, 4.2.0, 4.2.1
- deleting and reinstalling all node_modules
- cleaning build with **gradlew clean** and rebuilding again after each version change

Here's my **npm list** output:

```
├── @babel/core@7.14.2
├── @babel/runtime@7.14.0
├── @react-native-community/cli-platform-android@5.0.1-alpha.1
├── @react-native-community/eslint-config@2.0.0
├── @react-native-firebase/analytics@11.5.0
├── @react-native-firebase/app@11.5.0
├── @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@11.5.0
├── @react-native-firebase/functions@11.5.0
├── @react-native-firebase/messaging@11.5.0
├── babel-jest@26.6.3
├── eslint@7.26.0
├── fast-html-parser@1.0.1
├── jest@26.6.3
├── metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.66.0
├── react-native-keep-awake@4.0.0
├── react-native-mmkv-storage@0.5.8
├── react-native-print@0.7.0
├── react-native-sound-player@0.10.8
├── react-native-webview@11.4.4
├── react-native@0.64.1
├── react-test-renderer@17.0.2
├── react@17.0.2
└── util@0.12.3
```

I'm overriding to latest firebase BOM 28.0.1. Also tried default @react-native-firebase 26.8.0 version, then app crashes on start with no error output at build or metro.
App has **google-services.json** at android/app and is registered in firebase.
Currently using gradle 6.9, plugin 4.1.3, and google-services 4.3.5.

First time the messaging is used at index.js, listening for background push messages, as stated in docs at https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Later try to get device token and call cloud function:

```
 var switchFunction = functions().httpsCallable(toggleFunctionName);
  messaging()
    .getToken()
    .then((token) => {
      switchFunction({
        organization: encodeURI(parsedLocalData.organizationName),
        user_email: encodeURI(parsedLocalData.userMai),
        device_token: token,
      })
        .then((result) => {
          // Read result of the Cloud Function.
          var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
          console.log('Firebase: ' + sanitizedMessage);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Getting the Error details.
          console.log('Firebase error: ' + error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you figure it out ?

Comment: no, I didn't :( Need more senior devs to notice this..

Comment: I was able to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your `app/build.gradle` under dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid'
```

And this to the top level `build.gradle` under ext {}

```
firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
```

Also if you haven't done that already, under dependencies in your top level `build.gradle` :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
```

Finally, at the tope of `app/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Any explanation? Please confirm your decision. I see that Google Play Services v16 was released back in 2019. I would like to know if this is rational decision or better to wait for a fix from official devs of React Native Firebase at https://rnfirebase.io/

Comment: You can leave out the version of Google Play Services actually. Because 16.+ let's it take the latest version available I think.

Comment: 2020-12 google docs:  "FirebaseInstanceId - This class is deprecated. Firebase Instance ID has been replaced with FirebaseInstallations for app instance identifiers and FirebaseMessaging.getToken() for FCM registration tokens." https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/iid/package-summary
So why RN Firebase is not updated to support new classes?

Comment: Still not working for me with the same "error: cannot find symbol FirebaseInstanceId" after these changes..

Comment: Did u clean everything ./gradlew clean ?

Comment: @Neone Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find solution